# Big O complexity for recursive anagram algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, anagram

I am trying to return all the permutations of a string using a recursive method anagram(). For any word "ABCD...N", the function returns a list with the letter "A" in as many positions as possible within anagram("BCD...N"). The limiting case of the recursion would be that if the argument is of size two (eg: "XY"), it returns ['XY','YX'].

Code is as follows:

```
def anagram(block):
   if (len(block) <= 2):
      permu=list()
      permu.append(block[0]+block[1])
      permu.append(block[1]+block[0])
   else:
      permu=list()
      lowerpermu=anagram(block[1:])             # anag(sd)
      for blocklet in lowerpermu:           # sd, ds are blocklets
         for each in rotate(block[0],blocklet):     # each in ['asd', 'sad', 'sda'] and ['ads', 'das', 'dsa']
            permu.append(each)
   return permu


def rotate(letter, word):
   rotatedlist=list()
   for i in range(len(word)+1):
      rotatedlist.append(word[:i]+letter+word[i:])
   return rotatedlist

def main():
   word=raw_input('Enter the word to be anagrammed: ')  #for example: 'asd'
   print anagram(word)                  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am teaching myself general algorithms and their analysis, and I would be grateful if someone could suggest a rule of thumb method for estimating the order of algorithms where recursion is involved.

Comment: You should be able to do better than a "rule of thumb", you should be able to figure this out precisely.

Comment: Here's a tip for you, start with eliminating all code that do not affect runtime (computing results, etc).

Comment: If you teach yourself I suggest to follow this online course http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/

Comment: Thanks people. The Master Theorem seems to have done the trick.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)